# TypeError: 'checkValidity' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTextAreaElement

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I am facing this error and the email could not be sent because of this error. I have added a new extension Birthday reminder in opencart v2.0.1.1
I have searched about the error but could not resolve it. Please help. code for the file is this.

```
<form class="form mailForm">
    <div class="row form-group" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="brCustomerMailInfo">
              <label>To: </label>
            <strong><?php if(!empty($customerInfo['email'])) echo $customerInfo['email']; ?></strong>
              <input  type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php if(!empty($customerInfo['customer_id'])) echo $customerInfo['customer_id']; ?>"  />
              <input  type="hidden" name="to_mail" value="<?php if(!empty($customerInfo['email'])) echo $customerInfo['email'];?>"  />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="brCustomerMailInfo">
            <label>Born:</label>
          <strong><?php  if(!empty($customerInfo['birthday_date'])){ 
                              echo $customerInfo['birthday_date'];
                          }
                            ?></strong>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">  
          <div class="brCustomerMailInfo">
            <label>Age:</label>
            <strong>
              <?php if(!empty($customerInfo['birthday_date'])) {;
                      $now = new DateTime("now"); 
                      if (strpos($customerInfo['birthday_date'],'/') !== false) {
                        echo floor((time()-strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $customerInfo['birthday_date'])))/(365*60*60*24)) ;
                      } else {
                        echo floor((time()-strtotime($customerInfo['birthday_date']))/(365*60*60*24)) ;
                      }
                    }?>
            </strong>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h5><strong><?php echo $discount_code_text ?></strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <strong><?php echo $discount_code?></strong>
            <input type="hidden" class="brSmallField form-control" name="discount_code" value="<?php echo $discount_code?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><h5><strong><span class="required">* </span><?php echo $type_of_discount;?></strong></h5></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
              <select class="form-control" name="discount_type" > 
                  <option value="P"><?php echo $percentage_text?></option>
                  <option value="F" <?php if(!empty($data['BirthdayReminder']['discount_type']) && $data['BirthdayReminder']['discount_type'] == "F") echo "selected";?>><?php echo $fixed_amount; ?></option>
              </select>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><h5><strong><span class="required">* </span><?php echo $discount_text;?></strong></h5></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="brSmallField form-control" name="discount" value="<?php if(!empty($data['BirthdayReminder']['discount'])) echo $data['BirthdayReminder']['discount']; ?>">
                <span class="input-group-addon" >%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><h5><strong><span class="required">* </span><?php echo $total_amount; ?></strong></h5></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="brSmallField form-control" name="total_amount" value="<?php echo $data['BirthdayReminder']['total_amount'] ?>">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" ><?php echo $currency ?></span>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><h5><strong><span class="required">* </span>Subject:</strong></h5></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input placeholder="Mail subject" type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" name="subject" value="<?php if(!empty($data['BirthdayReminder']['subject'])) echo $data['BirthdayReminder']['subject']; else   echo $default_subject; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><h5><strong><span class="required">* </span><?php echo $user_email; ?></strong></h5></div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="giftMessage">
                <?php if(!empty($customerInfo)) {
                            $wordTemplates = array("{firstname}", "{lastname}", "{discount_code}");
                            $words   = array($customerInfo['firstname'], $customerInfo['lastname'], $discount_code);

                            if(!empty($data['BirthdayReminder']['message'][$customerInfo['language_id']])) { 
                                $message = str_replace($wordTemplates, $words,$data['BirthdayReminder']['message'][$customerInfo['language_id']]);
                                 echo $message;
                            } else {
                                $default_message = str_replace($wordTemplates, $words, $default_message);
                                 echo $default_message;
                            }
                    }?>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align: center"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="sendGift"><?php  echo $send_gift_button; ?></button></div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
  var gettingOptions = function () {
      $('textarea[id="giftMessage"]').each(function(index, element) {
      $('#'+element.id).summernote({
        height:150
      });

      $('.btn#sendGift').on('click', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentYear  = new Date().getFullYear();
        var errorInput = false;         

        if(!$('input[name="subject"]').val()){
          e.preventDefault();
          errorInput = true;
          $('input[name="subject"]').css({'background':'#f2dede'});
         }

         if(!validateNumber($('input[name="discount"]'), e)) {
           errorInput = true;
         }

         if(!validateNumber($('input[name="total_amount"]'), e)) {
          errorInput = true;
         }

        if(!errorInput) {
          var isSentGift = false;
          var lastGift = "<?php if(isset($customerInfo['last_gift_date'])){ $date = explode('-', $customerInfo['last_gift_date']); echo $date[0]; } else { echo '0';}?>";
          if(currentYear == lastGift){
            isSentGift= true;
          } 

          sentAgain = true;

          if(isSentGift) {
           var last_gift_date = "<?php if(!empty($customerInfo['last_gift_date'])) {
                          echo $customerInfo['last_gift_date']; 
                        } 
                        ?>";
           var sentAgain=confirm("A gift is sent to this customer on " + last_gift_date + ". Do you want to sent this again?");
          }

          if(sentAgain){
          $.ajax({
            url:      'index.php?route=<?php echo $modulePath;?>/sendGift&token=' + getURLVar('token') ,
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{  
              discount_code: $("input[name='discount_code']").val(),
              discount: $("input[name='discount']").val(),
              total_amount: $("input[name='total_amount']").val(),
              discount_type: $("select[name='discount_type']").val(),
              customer_id: $("input[name='customer_id']").val(),
              to_mail: $("input[name='to_mail']").val(),
              subject: $("input[name='subject']").val(),
              gift_message: $('#'+element.id).summernote('code') },
              type:     'POST',
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(data){
              $('.messageHasBeenSent').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(600);
              $('.btn.btn-link.active').click();
            }
          });
          }
          $("#sendEmailModal").modal('hide');
        } 
        else { 
        e.preventDefault();
        }
      });                      
    });
  };

  $("#sendEmailModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    gettingOptions();  
  });

  if($('select[name="discount_type"]').val() == 'P'){
    $('#percentageAddonForm').show();
  } else {
    $('#currencyAddonForm').show();
  }

$('select[name="discount_type"]').on('change', function(e){ 
  if($(this).val() == 'P') {
    $('#percentageAddonForm').show();
    $('#currencyAddonForm').hide();

  } else {
    $('#currencyAddonForm').show();
    $('#percentageAddonForm').hide();
  } 
});

  function validateNumber(input, theEvent) { 
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if(!regex.test(input.val())) {
      input.css({'background':'#f2dede'});
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this resolved!

```
if(sentAgain){
          $.ajax({
            url:      'index.php?route=<?php echo $modulePath;?>/sendGift&token=' + getURLVar('token') ,
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{  
              discount_code: $("input[name='discount_code']").val(),
              discount: $("input[name='discount']").val(),
              total_amount: $("input[name='total_amount']").val(),
              discount_type: $("select[name='discount_type']").val(),
              customer_id: $("input[name='customer_id']").val(),
              to_mail: $("input[name='to_mail']").val(),
              subject: $("input[name='subject']").val(),
              gift_message: $('#'+element.id).summernote('code') },
              type:     'POST',
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(data){
              $('.messageHasBeenSent').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(600);
              $('.btn.btn-link.active').click();
            }
          });
          }
```

This is the ajax call and this line was causing the problem

```
gift_message: $('#'+element.id).summernote('code')
```

So I change it with this

```
gift_message: $('#giftMessage').val()
```

the element was undefined in this case.